# Returning multiple values in a Java method which calls PLSQL procedure with multiple OUT parameters

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jdbc, return

I am creating a `SOAP Web service` by wrapping `PL/SQL` procedures in Java.I have java method that uses `JDBC` to call a PL/SQL procedure with multiple `OUT` parameters. I need this method to return values of all the OUT parameters. For instance

Here is the PL/SQL procedure header:

```
-- Purpose: print the employees manger details (id and name)
-- Example Of: Procedure  with multiple parameters of OUT type 
PROCEDURE get_empl_manager(emp_id employees.employee_id%type , mngr_id OUT employees.employee_id%type , manager_name OUT VARCHAR2);
```

Here is how I would return these two values. I have the following Java method signature:

```
public Manager getEmpManagerDetails(int empId)
```

Where Manager is a Class with following definition:

```
Class Manager
{
  int managerId;
  String managerName;
}
```

I am sure this will work but **I am wondering If there is a recommended/preferred way (in context of JDBC or SOAP) to return multiple values that you get from the PL/SQL procedures OUT parameters.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the next:

```
public Map<String, Object> getEmpManagerDetails(int empId) { ... }
```

Comment: It would work but would'nt the web service client then have to interpret what the object is using the lengthy if-else structure using "InstanceOf" operator?

Comment: It seems that you have to build a **class** with all the data. Because you need a handler to convert the XML/map to map/XML.

Comment: If I understood you right it seems like creating a class is the only way to return multiple values from the above method if a web service needs to be created out of it.

Comment: It is the most **simple** and **quick** process.